# Different 'make' behaviour

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel-module

I'm trying to write a makefile for a kernel module and cannot get it to work. Running the following has this output

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

but running the make command directly on the terminal results in

```
$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'
   CC [M] <blah>
   Building modules, stage 2
   <blah>
make: Leaving directory...
```

The contents of my Makefile are (source file is main.c)

```
obj-m += main.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
```

I do delete *.o and *.ko before trying to use the makefile. Changing `all` to `default` does nothing either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely issue is that you didn't use a *real* tab character to begin the line reading `make -C ...`, but instead used multiple spaces.  `make` requires that commands all begin with a tab character.

Comment: OMFG that was it, tabs. I need a cigarette

Answer (score 0):

I knew this like the back of my hand several years ago; I’ll do the best I can from memory.  The procedure is that `make` looks at all the subordinate targets (dependencies) listed after a target it has been asked to make and checks whether they are up to date. 
If they are all up to date, and the primary target is not older than any of them, we’re done.  Otherwise, execute the following commands. Thus, for

```
prog: main.o subr.o
    $(CC) main.o subr.o –o $@
```

If `subr.c` has been edited, we need to recompile it to bring `subr.o` up to date. 
Then, since `subr.o` is newer than `prog`, we run the commands to relink `prog`.

The devil lives in the boundary conditions.  Your `all` pseudo-target has no dependencies. 
*Therefore, **none of the dependencies** is newer than the* `all` *target.* 
Therefore, we don’t do the commnd(s) below the `all`.

ISTR that I “fixed” this by saying

> `all: always`
>          *command(s)…*

where `always` is not a keyword, but is just a user-chosen pseudo-filename (like `all`, `clean`, `new`, etc.), chosen to remind you that it is there to force the command(s) under the `all` to be run always. Then put

> `always:`
>                                  *<– blank line (no commands)*

somewhere else in the Makefile.

---

That’s peculiar: I thought I just saw an answer from [Philipp Claßen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783510/philipp-classen) here, but then it disappeared.  Anyway, he said

> Your target has no dependents, so `make` assumes that nothing needs to be done. 
>   You have to declare your target as `.PHONY`.
>
> [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) is a link to the documentation.

So now you know the “right” (non-kludge) way to handle the problem.

Comment: FYI: you should be able delete your own answer, then edit it while it is deleted, save it, and undelete it. Certainly, at higher rep levels, that's possible. This gives you a chance to repair an answer that you're not happy with.  It also saves you being asked about 'do you really want to add another answer to this question'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I’m not sure exactly what you’re referring to, but, FYI, I posted that second copy of the same answer _by accident_.  But thanks for the suggestion; I may use it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but the issue was the IDE substituting spaces for tabs

Comment: Scott — 10k users can see deleted answers; I wasn't sure how you ended up with two answers, but one possibility was that you weren't happy with a first version, deleted it (but copied the material) and then created a second answer.  The other possibility (which hadn't occurred to me) was an accidental repost.  Not to worry; you did nothing formally wrong.